# Shiny App: How to dynamically change box title in server.R?

Tags: r, shiny

The box title is usually set in ui.R. Is it possible to change the box title dynamically in server.R?

`ui.R`

`box(title='Dynamic title here', plotOutput('barPlot'))`

`server.R`

`output$barPlot= renderPlot({...})` # Can I dynamically change the box title here?

**Edit:**

Here's a simple code to try

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=6,
           box(
             title = 'Dynamic title',
             width = NULL,
             plotOutput('speed', height='100%')
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$speed <- renderPlot({
    plot(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
    # need a code to change the box title
  }, height=300)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Yes, you can change your box title inside of renderPlot on the server.R side of things. Should be straight forward. Would need to see better code examples to help any further...

Comment: Have added a sample code. Let me know if you can change the title in renderPlot.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out, using `renderUI`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    textInput("title", "What should the tile be?"),
    uiOutput("box1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$speed <- renderPlot({
    plot(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
  })

  output$box1 <- renderUI({
    validate(
      need(input$title, "Please enter a valid title!")
    )
    box(title = input$title, plotOutput("speed"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is okay, but it requires writing 2 outputs to get it done (renderUI > renderPlot).